# Problema con chatterBot

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo este error al ejecutar el chatterbot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hcamp\workspace\proyecto-personal\chatbot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>  
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.logic import LogicAdapter
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\logic\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.logic.logic_adapter import LogicAdapter
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\logic\logic_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.search import IndexedTextSearch
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\search.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.conversation import Statement
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\conversation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytz import UTC
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

Comment: Esto -> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'`. Ahí pone literalmente que no se encuentra el módulo `pytz`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero tengo otra pregunta porque tambien me aparece esto
Instance of 'ChatBot' has no 'set_trainer' memberpylint

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que te falta el módulo pytz.
Es necesario instalarlo para que puedas usarlo mediante pip (fuera del intérprete de python).

> pip install pytz

Respecto al comentario, ¿qué versión de ChatBot usas?
Según la documentación estable, es necesario entrenar al ChatBot mediante *train*.

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]

chatbot = ChatBot("Ron Obvious")

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train(conversation)
```

Comment: la version que estoy utilizando es 1.0.4 y ahora me da este error AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Comment: Qué versión de python usas? Acabo de mirar y esa función se eliminó de python3.8, por lo que si usas esa versión, sería recomendable que probaras con otra. @Harold

Comment: la versión 3.9 de python pero si trato de instalar otra versión de chatterbot me lanza un error

Comment: ¿Qué error te salta? También puedes cambiar la línea donde te salta el error, time.clock() cambiarlo por time.time(). Edit: prueba a instalar la versión 1.0.7 de chatterbot, que contiene las correcciones pertinentes con el comando: pip install chatterbot==1.0.7

Comment: tengo este error si trato de instalar la version 1.0.7 o la version 1.0.8 (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatterbot==1.0.7
ERROR: No matching distribution found for chatterbot==1.0.7)

Comment: ¿Puedes probar con este comando? python3 -m pip install chatterbot==1.0.7. Si sigue sin funcionar, ¿podrías indicarme la salida del comando python3 -m pip --version? @Harold

Comment: no me permite instalar Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes instalado python? ¿Has añadido python a las variables de entorno de windows? https://www.kyocode.com/2019/10/agregar-python-path-windows/ @Harold

Comment: si lo tengo echo el problema esta cuando se esta instalando que me da error al instalar las dependencias y solo me deja instalar la version 1.0.4

Comment: ¿Puedes indicarme la traza de error donde te sale el error de AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'? @Harold

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
  File "C:\Users\hcamp\workspace\proyecto-personal\chatbot.py", line 6, in <module>
    bot = ChatBot('YO')

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que busques el código de donde tienes instalado chatterbot, debería estar en alguna ruta similar a C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\, busca la línea donde aparece time.clock y cambiala por time.time

Comment: Ok voy hacer eso y te comento